# How do I post a question in Stack Exchange successfully?

Tags: support

I posted a question on this website a week ago, but it has been closed because the topic is off-topic. How can I choose the right topic and where can I look for it? I have newly joined this website. It confused me.

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually talking about this meta site? Or some other site (like Stack Overflow)?

Answer (score 2):

If you did not take the Tour and review the On-topic page of that site before asking your question then I think those should be your first steps.

These are links to those pages on this site and every site has their own:

- [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [On-topic page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)